# How can I reverse a video clip?

Tags: video

My OS is Debian 8.

I have a file named `clip01.mp4` that I would like to reverse, so it plays backwards. Audio can be discarded or reversed as well, doesn't matter.

Apparently `ffmpeg` is deprecated in favor of `avconv`, but I can't seem to find a solution that uses either tool!

I would like to keep the same video codec to avoid any sort of losses, if possible.

Command line tools are preferred, for ease of scripting.

Comment: To do this with ffmpeg / avconv you have to split the video into single frames, rename the frames so they are in reverse order, then build a new video. Take a look at [encode video in reverse?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2553448/4014959)

Comment: Have you tried with avidemux or kino?

Comment: [`ffmpeg` is not, in fact, deprecated](http://superuser.com/a/507473/176100) (though that's a common misunderstanding thanks to some poor wording on `avconv`'s part…).

Comment: Ffmpeg is not deprecated anymore https://lwn.net/Articles/650495/

Answer (score 17):

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553448:

Dump all video frames

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.mkv -an -qscale 1 %06d.jpg
```

Dump audio

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vn -ac 2 audio.wav
```

Reverse audio

```
$ sox -V audio.wav backwards.wav reverse
```

Cat video frames in reverse order to FFmpeg as input

```
$ cat $(ls -t *jpg) | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -vcodec mjpeg -r 25 -i - -i backwards.wav -vcodec libx264 -vpre slow -crf 20 -threads 0 -acodec flac output.mkv
```

Use mencoder to deinterlace PAL dv and double the frame rate from 25 to 50, then pipe to FFmpeg.

```
$ mencoder input.dv -of rawvideo -ofps 50 -ovc raw -vf yadif=3,format=i420 -nosound -really-quiet -o - | ffmpeg -vsync 0 -f rawvideo -s 720x576 -r 50 -pix_fmt yuv420p -i - -vcodec libx264 -vpre slow -crf 20 -threads 0 video.mkv
```

Comment: `cat $(ls -t *jpg)` caused trouble, but this worked great `cat $(ls *jpg |sort -n)`

Comment: Ateempting to use `-vpre slow` resulted in `File for preset 'slow' not found`.

Comment: Also, I am not sure is it problem of vlc/mplayer or presented process but produced file is unplayable - in mplayer only left half is displayed and video display is very laggy, vlc crashes on opening video file.

Comment: It's possible to extract the frame rate into a variable using the command `FRAME_RATE=$(ffmpeg -i "$VIDEO_FILE" 2>&1 | grep -o -P '[0-9\\. ]+fps' | grep -o -P '[0-9\\.]+')` (basically get the number in front of fps in ffmpeg). Then you can pass the actual frame rate instead of hard-coding 25. I know this question says sound can be discarded, but in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553448/encode-video-in-reverse/68519663#68519663 I posted a bash script that reverses the audio and keeps it synchronized (based on the fps), if someone wants to keep audio.

Comment: `ls -r *.jpg` is even better

Comment: There is a specific tool to extract file information, ffprobe

`ffprobe -v 0 -of csv=p=0 -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=r_frame_rate "$src"`

Answer (score 6):

kdenlive reverse clip https://userbase.kde.org/Kdenlive/Manual/Project_Menu/Reverse_Clip

right-click on the clip: clip jobs / reverse clip

Comment: Indeed kdenlive 15.12.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 has this feature and it works.

Comment: I am using Kdenlive Version 17.12.3 and there is no "reverse clip" option anymore

Comment: No, but there's "duplicate with speed change" and "-100%" is reverse in normal speed.

Answer (score 4):

In Debian there's *Avidemux* program, with *Reverse* video filter. Just tested - works perfectly.

GTK, QT and command line versions available.

Edit: this plugin has been removed in Avidemux ver. 2.6. Use 2.5.6 and older.

Comment: There's currently no avidemux package in official Debian repositories as per https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=avidemux&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

Answer (score 4):

You could also use [Openshot](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=openshot) it's a very intuitive an easy to use video editor.

You have to right click on the imported clip then properties -> speed tab, change the direction of the clip.

Comment: In my case openshot refused to import .mp4 as video.

Comment: In recent OpenShots (mine is 2.4.1), the setting is now called Time and it is *not* in the video clip properties; you have to right-click the clip itself in the timeline and then choose Time -> Backwards -> 1X or similar.

Answer (score 2):

All the other answers were seemingly written in the time before [ffmpeg](/questions/tagged/ffmpeg) had a video filter called `reverse`.

So, on any standard Linux system, a recentish `ffmpeg` allows:

```
ffmpeg -i input.video.file.name -vf reverse -o output.file.mkv
```

Answer (score 1):

AviSynth has a [Reverse()](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/Reverse) command, which could be used ...

also see: "[how do I make a video play backwards on virtual dub?](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/233333-How-do-I-make-a-video-play-backwards-on-virtual-dub)"